Onsager conjecture and properties of Besov Spaces
I am currently studying the result in  Peter Constantin 1, Weinan E, and E. S. Titi, Onsager’s Conjecture on the Energy Conservation for Solutions
of Euler’s Equation
link:https://web.math.princeton.edu/~weinan/papers/misc1.pdf
The result of the paper is basically proof of the weak part of Onsager conjecture in the periodic domain. In the first part of paper authors give bounds on $L^3$ norm of several terms in terms of Besov norms. More specifically:

I believe that some of the inequalities could be somehow shown form the definition of norm in $B^{\alpha,\infty}_3$ and Minkowski inequality. However especially in (7) and (8), I could not find a way to do this on my own. Any help as to showing why these inequalities hold is greatly appreciated.

It is more intuitive if you give up the compactly supported constraint and consider the Fourier side to be compactly supported.
Let Littlewood-Paley norm is $\|f\|_{B_p^{\alpha\infty}}=\sup_{j\ge0}2^{j\alpha}\|\Delta_jf\|_{L^p}$ where $(\Delta_jf)^\wedge(\xi):=(\chi(2^{-j}\xi)-\chi(2^{1-j}\xi))\hat f(\xi)$ for some $\chi\in C_c^\infty(B(0,2))$ such that $\chi|_{B(0,1)}\equiv1$. You can choose $\hat\varphi_\epsilon(\xi)=\chi(\xi/\epsilon)$.
In this case $u-u^{2^{-j}}=\sum_{k=j+1}^\infty\Delta_ku$ which gives $$\|u-u^{2^{-j}}\|_{L^p}\le\sum_{k=j+1}^\infty\|\Delta_ku\|_{L^p}\le\sum_{k=j+1}^\infty2^{-k\alpha}\|u\|_{B_p^{\alpha\infty}}\approx2^{-j\alpha}\|u\|_{B_p^{\alpha\infty}}.$$
Note that $\Delta_j=\sum_{k=j-1}^{j+1}\Delta_k\Delta_j$ we see that $\|\nabla\Delta_ju\|_{L^p}\lesssim\sum_{k=j-1}^{j+1}2^k\|\Delta_ku\|_{L^p}$ (the constant depends on $\|\hat\chi\|_{W^{1,\infty}}$). So $$\|\nabla u^{2^{-j}}\|_{L^p}\le\sum_{k=0}^j\|\nabla\Delta_ju\|_{B_p^{\alpha\infty}}\lesssim\sum_{k=0}^{j+1}2^k2^{-k\alpha}\|u\|_{B_p^{\alpha\infty}}\approx2^{j(1-\alpha)}\|u\|_{B_p^{\alpha\infty}}.$$
The general result where $\epsilon\neq2^{-j}$ and the estimates for general "standard mollifier" can be done by working on suitable tail decay estimates.
